# Matlab crashes when plotting specific 3D functions

Tags: matlab

Matlab crashes (closes) when I try to plot a 3D function of the like z=(x,y), whenever the function involves the following conditions **together**:

- incorrect multiplication and power notation: e.g. x*y^2 instead of x.*y.^2
- x,y support grid very small: e.g. meshgrid(0.01:.01:0.99)

For example, the following code doesn't work:

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(0.01:.01:0.99);
z=x*y^2;
surf(z)
```

Same happens if I use `mesh` instead of `surf`. Normally, you would expect an error about the notation.

It seems to be a bug of Matlab. An automatic crash report contain this:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Illegal instruction detected at Fri Aug  7 15:59:56 2015
------------------------------------------------------------------------

Configuration:
  Crash Decoding      : Disabled
  Crash Mode          : continue (default)
  Current Graphics Driver: ATI Technologies Inc. AMD Radeon HD 8400 / R3 Series Version 4.4.13374 Compatibility Profile Context 15.20.1013
  Current Visual      : 0x23 (class 4, depth 24)
  Default Encoding    : UTF-8
  GNU C Library       : 2.19 stable
  Host Name           : -------
  MATLAB Architecture : glnxa64
  MATLAB Root         : /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a
  MATLAB Version      : 8.5.0.197613 (R2015a)
  OpenGL              : hardware
  Operating System    : Linux 3.16.0-45-generic #60~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 24 21:16:23 UTC 2015 x86_64
  Processor ID        : x86 Family 127 Model 0 Stepping 1, AuthenticAMD
  Virtual Machine     : Java 1.7.0_60-b19 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
  Window System       : The X.Org Foundation (11600000), display :0.0

Fault Count: 4


Abnormal termination:
Illegal instruction

Register State (from fault):
  RAX = 00007feb4c01b000  RBX = 00007feb4c01e000
  RCX = 0000000000000010  RDX = 00007febabd64e80
  RSP = 00007feb20d48400  RBP = 0000000000000018
  RSI = 0000000000000000  RDI = 00007feb20d484d0

   R8 = 0000000000000400   R9 = 00007feb4c01e000
  R10 = 0000000000000948  R11 = 0000000000000318
  R12 = 0000000000000020  R13 = 0000000000000018
  R14 = 0000000000000040  R15 = 0000000000000020

  RIP = 00007feb0bf47e02  EFL = 0000000000010216

   CS = 0033   FS = 0000   GS = 0000

Stack Trace (from fault):
[  0] 0x00007feb0bf47e02        /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/mkl.so+30535170 mkl_blas_cnr_def_dgemm_kernel_bdz+00000210
[  1] 0x00007feb0bf3f665        /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/mkl.so+30500453 mkl_blas_cnr_def_xdgemm_bdz+00001381
[  2] 0x00007feb0a4dbe4f        /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/mkl.so+02829903 mkl_blas_dgemm_2d_bsrc+00000527
[  3] 0x00007feb0a4d709e        /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/mkl.so+02810014
[  4] 0x00007febb8bd3623 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libiomp5.so+00558627 __kmp_invoke_microtask+00000147
[  5] 0x00007febb8babf64 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libiomp5.so+00397156
[  6] 0x00007febb8baae02 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libiomp5.so+00392706
[  7] 0x00007febb8bd38d9 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libiomp5.so+00559321
[  8] 0x00007febcd62f182              /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0+00033154
[  9] 0x00007febcd35c47d                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+01025149 clone+00000109
[ 10] 0x0000000000000000                                   <unknown-module>+00000000


Abnormal termination:
Illegal instruction

Register State (from fault):
  RAX = 00007febabd95000  RBX = 00007febabd97000
  RCX = 0000000000000010  RDX = 00007febabd64c40
  RSP = 00007febb7ea4d00  RBP = 0000000000000018
  RSI = 0000000000000000  RDI = 00007febb7ea4dd0

   R8 = 0000000000000400   R9 = 00007febabd97000
  R10 = 0000000000000948  R11 = 0000000000000318
  R12 = 0000000000000020  R13 = 0000000000000018
  R14 = 0000000000000040  R15 = 0000000000000020

  RIP = 00007feb0bf47e02  EFL = 0000000000010216

   CS = 0033   FS = 0000   GS = 0000

Stack Trace (from fault):
[  0] 0x00007feb0bf47e02        /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/mkl.so+30535170 mkl_blas_cnr_def_dgemm_kernel_bdz+00000210
[  1] 0x00007feb0bf3f665        /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/mkl.so+30500453 mkl_blas_cnr_def_xdgemm_bdz+00001381
[  2] 0x00007feb0a4dbe4f        /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/mkl.so+02829903 mkl_blas_dgemm_2d_bsrc+00000527
[  3] 0x00007feb0a4d709e        /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/mkl.so+02810014
[  4] 0x00007febb8bd3623 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libiomp5.so+00558627 __kmp_invoke_microtask+00000147
[  5] 0x00007febb8babf64 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libiomp5.so+00397156
[  6] 0x00007febb8bad26a /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libiomp5.so+00402026 __kmp_fork_call+00004474
[  7] 0x00007febb8b8c2e8 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libiomp5.so+00266984 __kmpc_fork_call+00000200
[  8] 0x00007feb0a4d6cf0        /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/mkl.so+02809072
[  9] 0x00007feb0a4d2db3        /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/mkl.so+02792883 mkl_blas_dgemm+00001475
[ 10] 0x00007feb0a9d23b2        /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/mkl.so+08033202 mkl_lapack_dgehrd+00001826
[ 11] 0x00007feb0a9d65a2        /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/mkl.so+08050082 mkl_lapack_dgeevx+00002706
[ 12] 0x00007feb0a350537        /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/mkl.so+01209655 dgeevx_+00000327
[ 13] 0x00007feb32addf04 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmathlinalg.so+01310468
[ 14] 0x00007feb32adc875 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmathlinalg.so+01304693
[ 15] 0x00007feb32a6b4a2 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmathlinalg.so+00840866
[ 16] 0x00007feb32a6b83e /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmathlinalg.so+00841790
[ 17] 0x00007febc217d305 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00557829
[ 18] 0x00007febc2164744 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00456516 _ZN13Mfh_MATLAB_fn11dispatch_fhEiPP11mxArray_tagiS2_+00000244
[ 19] 0x00007febc142bd20 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+04189472
[ 20] 0x00007febc13db432 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+03859506
[ 21] 0x00007febc13dd612 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+03868178
[ 22] 0x00007febc13e3597 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+03892631
[ 23] 0x00007febc13decff /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+03874047
[ 24] 0x00007febc13df934 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+03877172
[ 25] 0x00007febc14552ce /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+04358862
[ 26] 0x00007febc21bbaea /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00813802 _ZN8Mfh_file16dispatch_fh_implEMS_FviPP11mxArray_tagiS2_EiS2_iS2_+00000762
[ 27] 0x00007febc21bbfb0 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00815024 _ZN8Mfh_file11dispatch_fhEiPP11mxArray_tagiS2_+00000032
[ 28] 0x00007febb52e8edd /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcos_impl.so+02473693
[ 29] 0x00007febb527e5c2 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcos_impl.so+02037186
[ 30] 0x00007febb527fddf /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcos_impl.so+02043359
[ 31] 0x00007febb52858e0 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcos_impl.so+02066656
[ 32] 0x00007febb5281053 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcos_impl.so+02048083
[ 33] 0x00007febb52efbb6 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcos_impl.so+02501558
[ 34] 0x00007febb537471b /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcos_impl.so+03045147
[ 35] 0x00007febc2164744 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00456516 _ZN13Mfh_MATLAB_fn11dispatch_fhEiPP11mxArray_tagiS2_+00000244
[ 36] 0x00007febb5372451 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcos_impl.so+03036241
[ 37] 0x00007feb32a9737c /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmathlinalg.so+01020796
[ 38] 0x00007febc217d305 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00557829
[ 39] 0x00007febc2164744 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00456516 _ZN13Mfh_MATLAB_fn11dispatch_fhEiPP11mxArray_tagiS2_+00000244
[ 40] 0x00007febc154dfee /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+05378030
[ 41] 0x00007febc147ca71 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+04520561
[ 42] 0x00007febc147d7ee /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+04524014
[ 43] 0x00007febc1489619 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+04572697
[ 44] 0x00007febc1489783 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+04573059
[ 45] 0x00007febc15c0b54 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+05847892
[ 46] 0x00007febc13dd9b9 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+03869113
[ 47] 0x00007febc13e3597 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+03892631
[ 48] 0x00007febc13decff /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+03874047
[ 49] 0x00007febc13df934 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+03877172
[ 50] 0x00007febc14552ce /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+04358862
[ 51] 0x00007febc21bbc39 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00814137 _ZN8Mfh_file16dispatch_fh_implEMS_FviPP11mxArray_tagiS2_EiS2_iS2_+00001097
[ 52] 0x00007febc21bbfb0 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00815024 _ZN8Mfh_file11dispatch_fhEiPP11mxArray_tagiS2_+00000032
[ 53] 0x00007febc142bd20 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+04189472
[ 54] 0x00007febc13ac4b3 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+03667123
[ 55] 0x00007febc13dc6ee /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+03864302
[ 56] 0x00007febc13e3597 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+03892631
[ 57] 0x00007febc13decff /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+03874047
[ 58] 0x00007febc13df934 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+03877172
[ 59] 0x00007febc14552ce /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+04358862
[ 60] 0x00007febc21bbc39 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00814137 _ZN8Mfh_file16dispatch_fh_implEMS_FviPP11mxArray_tagiS2_EiS2_iS2_+00001097
[ 61] 0x00007febc21bbfb0 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00815024 _ZN8Mfh_file11dispatch_fhEiPP11mxArray_tagiS2_+00000032
[ 62] 0x00007febc1414495 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+04093077
[ 63] 0x00007febc13d4fb9 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+03833785
[ 64] 0x00007febc13d13f5 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+03818485
[ 65] 0x00007febc13d1ad3 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+03820243
[ 66] 0x00007febc30c7b6c /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwbridge.so+00228204
[ 67] 0x00007febc30c8751 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwbridge.so+00231249 _Z8mnParserv+00000737
[ 68] 0x00007febce7cc3af   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00799663 _ZN11mcrInstance30mnParser_on_interpreter_threadEv+00000031
[ 69] 0x00007febce7ac133   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00667955
[ 70] 0x00007febce7adfd9   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00675801 _ZN5boost6detail11task_objectIvNS_3_bi6bind_tIvPFvRKNS_8functionIFvvEEEENS2_5list1INS2_5valueIS6_EEEEEEE6do_runEv+00000025
[ 71] 0x00007febce7ae9a7   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00678311 _ZN5boost6detail9task_baseIvE3runEv+00000071
[ 72] 0x00007febce7aea07   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00678407
[ 73] 0x00007febce7a9d8a   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00658826
[ 74] 0x00007febc0767a56   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwuix.so+00334422
[ 75] 0x00007febc074f3a2   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwuix.so+00234402
[ 76] 0x00007febcef9af1f /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwservices.so+02621215
[ 77] 0x00007febcef9b08c /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwservices.so+02621580
[ 78] 0x00007febcef9cbdf /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwservices.so+02628575
[ 79] 0x00007febcef9d61c /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwservices.so+02631196 _Z25svWS_ProcessPendingEventsiib+00000092
[ 80] 0x00007febce7aa408   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00660488
[ 81] 0x00007febce7aa724   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00661284
[ 82] 0x00007febce796b0d   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00580365
[ 83] 0x00007febcd62f182              /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0+00033154
[ 84] 0x00007febcd35c47d                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+01025149 clone+00000109
[ 85] 0x0000000000000000                                   <unknown-module>+00000000


Abnormal termination
If this problem is reproducible, please submit a Service Request via:
    http://www.mathworks.com/support/contact_us/

A technical support engineer might contact you with further information.

Thank you for your help.
```

In suggestion from this forum, I submitted a service request. Clearly, I solved my problem by using the correct dot notation. Yet, regardless of any wrong notation, Matlab should not crash. I will update this post once I receive further information and either delete or answer this question.

Comment: Looks to me like something you should report to the Mathworks.  It's paid for software, let them do their own user support.

Comment: Illegal Instruction?  Sounds like it's something we can't solve.  Suggest you contact MathWorks support as per @HighPerformanceMark.

Comment: Solved! what a noob mistake. I had to make point-by-point multiplication... just adding a point before the multiplication and power symbols like `.*` and `.^` Should I eliminate this question or might it be useful for someone as dumb as me?

Comment: I still think you should report this to the Mathworks -- sure you omitted a . but I don't see why that should have crashed the software.  I think you should eliminate the question, but others may think differently.

Comment: @luchonacho No! the multiplication should not have crashed anything! Contact Mathworks!

Comment: Yes that crash should have not happened. I suggest you submit a report to MathWorks, regardless of whether the operation you intended was correct.

Comment: Well thought. I have submitted a service request and will wait for their reply before answering/closing this question.